# Laravel Middleware Assigning Multiple Role not Worked

Tags: laravel, middleware, roles

Hi guys i am having a trouble with my work. i tried many time to put two roles in route to ensure those will be granted access to specific page, but my other role which is employee still can access it. do you guys any comments? help!

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [
  'as' => 'admin',
  'uses' => 'DashboardController@index',
  'middleware' => ['roles:Staff,Owner','auth']
```

Comment: Did you register your middleware in the kernal.php file?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add as more parameter to your `handle()` function in middleware.

In your role middleware -

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role1, $role2)
{
  $role1 //Staff
  $role2 //Owner
}
```

If you're using PHP 7 -

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$role)
{
  $role //[Staff, Owner]
}
```